# Correcting times

Tags: sql, sql-server, datetime, error-correction

I have a table that has a datetime field called [avg time to answer].  For certain records the time is displaying incorrectly as shown below:

```
1899-12-30 01:04:00.000
1899-12-30 01:05:00.000
1899-12-30 01:30:00.000
```

The times shown here are wrong.  Times shown above are as small sample but they need to be formatted in minutes seconds rather than hours and minutes

Is there a way to correct this with a SQL script as the alternative involves extracting the data again and that is going to be extremely difficult and time consuming to do.

Comment: There is, but How will you identify those *certain* records?

Comment: You want to move the values of Minutes to Seconds and Hour to Minutes?

Comment: Correct I want to show the time as being 00:01:30 where is currently showing as 01:30:00 and show the minutes as seconds.  I'm not sure about how to identify particular records but that's some which can be figured out.

Comment: How do these records get populated? How is it possible that it would be incorrect only for *certain* records, unless there is a bug in the logic used to populate these records?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [DATEPART](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/ms174420.aspx):

> Returns an integer that represents the specified datepart of the specified date.

Combined with [DATEADD](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/ms186819.aspx):

> Returns a specified date with the specified number interval (signed integer) added to a specified datepart of that date.

**Example:**

```
DECLARE @val AS DATETIME = '1899-12-30 01:30:00.000';

SELECT  @val; -- 1899-12-30 01:30:00.000

SET @val = DATEADD(SECOND, DATEPART(MINUTE, @val),
                   DATEADD(MINUTE, ( DATEPART(HOUR, @val) ),
                           CAST(CAST(@val AS DATE) AS DATETIME)));

SELECT  @val; -- 1899-12-30 00:01:30.000
```

This casts the value to a `date`, to strip off the time portion and back to a `datetime` to set the time to `00:00:00`. Then adds minutes based on the hour value and seconds based on the minute value.

You can use this with an `UPDATE` statement, but ensure you use a `WHERE` clause to avoid updating everything, unless that's what you intend.

**Example Update Query:**

```
CREATE TABLE #temp
    (
      AvgTimeToAnswer DATETIME
    );

INSERT  INTO #temp
        ( AvgTimeToAnswer )
VALUES  ( '1899-12-30 01:30:00.000' );

SELECT  *
FROM    #temp; -- 1899-12-30 01:30:00.000

UPDATE  #temp
SET     AvgTimeToAnswer = DATEADD(SECOND, DATEPART(MINUTE, AvgTimeToAnswer),
                              DATEADD(MINUTE,
                                      ( DATEPART(HOUR, AvgTimeToAnswer) ),
                                      CAST(CAST(AvgTimeToAnswer AS DATE) AS DATETIME)));
-- WHERE some condition

SELECT  *
FROM    #temp; -- 1899-12-30 00:01:30.000

DROP TABLE #temp;
```